# This site doesn't support LaTex?

Tags: discussion, status-bydesign

It seems this site doesn't support LaTex
Then how to type math symbol here?
I tried to type $\wedge \vee \neg$,and still nothing happened.

Comment: I'll mark this as status-bydesign, but I would encourage anyone that wants to build support for this to answer this question with specific posts on the Ask Different site where having this support would help. I'm sure we could build consensus for a change if there were a documented need of the site not working well due to lack of LaTex support.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are correct; this site does not support LaTeX.

Most [Stack Exchange sites have opted out of supporting this LaTex extensions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30559/latex-in-stack-overflow) since it slows the site access for each and every user of the site whether they need the math rendering or not.

In general, there is little to no demand for this "feature" in the context of a web site answering questions about Apple products.

If you did need to insert special characters (which your question didn't *really* need to specify; saying "special characters" or "logic symbols" would have worked), the answer to how to insert them on this website is the same as the answer to your question about how to insert them in pages: use the character palate.

In your case, the three symbols are all standard unicode under Math Symbols:

- \wedge is ⋀ - the N-ARY LOGICAL AND character
- \vee is ⋁ - the N-ARY LOGICAL OR character
- \neg is ¬ - the NOT SIGN character

Comment: In order to write the question you need to know the answer? :-) But I agree: the demand for math symbols on AD is rather small.

Comment: That was my point. You don't need to know the answer in order to write the question. :-)

Comment: Also - this meta discussion explains that everyone's site load times are increased to support it's use on just a few posts and answers. I'll edit this answer to have that link.

Comment: This answer is too perfect,you even give the expiation of LaTex code I wrote